# Thunderbird Quota Root 100%

Tags: thunderbird, root, quota

If I remove the emails from the server would it effect my emails on Thunderbird?

Is there a way were Thunderbird just removes messages from server every 1-3 days? (like outlook does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on if you're using IMAP or POP3.

If you're using IMAP then yes as it is designed to sync certain folders. As such, you could create a new folder called "offline inbox", and then have a have a rule which moved the emails into this new folder. I'm not familiar with the rules in Thunderbird but I'd guess you can apply this for emails older than N days or similar. An example http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2168249

Of course, if you move emails from the folder to another unsynced folder then you lose the benefit of having IMAP (to a certain amount) as these emails won't appear on other devices!

If you're using POP3, then no as POP3 is designed to download the email. In email clients you have the option to delete the email after N days (if at all). More detail: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1105720

Outlook does not "do this" by default. It can be set up to work that way though.

Comment: IMAP here, how can I set up for it to delete incoming messages from server, but keep it in the Thunderbird? Any clue?

Comment: @AkmalSoliev, look at my update